# Aggregation vs Ternary relationship - When to use?

Tags: database-design, erd

I am reading a book about database systems and in the chapter covering database design using ER, the author aims to explain when to use `aggregation` versus `ternary relationship`. In short, each `Project entity` is sponsored by one or more `Department entities` and each `Department` can sponsor zero, one or more `Project`s. Each `Sponsorship` relationship has a `Monitors relationship`, which connects Employees with Sponsorship.

This can be expressed in 2 ER diagrams:

[image]

[image]

Now, we want to express an additional constraint that each `Sponsorship relationship` is monitored by at most one `Employee`.The author states that this cannot be done with ternary relationship. I can't wrap my head around why. To express this in diagrams, I would just point an arrow from `Sponsors2` to `Emplyees` in ternary relation. Does this not satisfy the additional constraint?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that we attempt to mix a key constraint ("each `Sponsorship relationship` is monitored by at most one `Employee`) with a participation constraint ("each project must be sponsored by at least one department," indicated by the bold line).

In a ternary relationship, we would be trying to impose a total participation of the `Project` entity set, while also trying to impose a one-to-many relationship between `Employee`s and (`Project`,`Department`) tuples. The ER diagram is not equipped to handle this in a ternary relationship -- how would it know whether the one-to-many relationship was between `Employees` and `Project`s, `Employee`s and `Department`s, or `Employee`s and (`Project`,`Department`) tuples?

Note that, for any entity in an n-ary relationship, you are allowed to force a unique (one-to-one or many-to-one) key constraint between said entity and all other entities in the relationship (indicated by an arrow), or force a participation constraint (indicated by a bolded line). One-to-one or many-to-one relationships in a ternary (or higher-degree) relationship between one entity and the rest of the entities in the relationship are unambiguous -- these are akin to adding a `UNIQUE` constraint in a table -- but one-to-many or many-to-many relationships are not and must be modeled with an aggregate relationship.